# Snowflake inner join bad performance over left join

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 equivalent queries in Snowflake - one with left join and the other with inner join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON a.id=b.id;

SELECT * 
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON a.id=b.id
WHERE b.id IS NOT NULL;
```

The inner join does not finish after an hour while the left join takes only few seconds. Why would it happen?

EDIT:
[image: Inner join]

[image: Left join]

Comment: Can you run both queries with `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` and show us the output? Also, how many rows and columns do both tables have?

Comment: ~10 columns, ~10 million rows each.

Comment: And the first part?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot added

Comment: About the execution plan, seems like the only difference is the extra filter in the left join (added to give the same results as the inner)

Comment: It looks like the query plans correspond to much more complex queries than the one in your answer. Is that true? If so, if you simplify the queries, do you get the same result? Does any of the unmentioned subqueries come from a `CTE`/`VALUES`/`generate_series`? I ask because those very often lose all grip on query statistics, and can confuse the planner.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219910/discussion-between-stav-hacohen-and-ruben-helsloot).

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities.

One is that there is really a difference in performance between the queries.  That would occur because Snowflake chooses very different execution plans for the two queries.  Of course the queries are not the same, but I might expect the execution plans to be similar.  You can check [`explain`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/explain.html) to investigate this.

The second is that the queries actually have quite similar performance, but you start seeing results from the first query quickly.  Why?  Because every row in the first table is going to be in the result set -- even if there is no match.  By contrast, if there is no match at all between the two tables, the second query has to process *all* the data before it knows there is no match.

Comment: I've added the execution plans. They look very much the same.
About your second point - it is not only the output that I see quicker, the LEFT query completes while the INNER keeps running for hours.